# Verneinung von "Er mag schwimmen"

Tags: usage, negation

> Er mag schwimmen.

Kann man diesen Satz so verneinen:

> Er mag nicht schwimmen.

?

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, denn ich habe diese Konstruktion nicht gesehen. Stattdessen ist mir

> Er schwimmt nicht gern.

gewohnter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beides ist in diesem Fall möglich, es gibt jedoch einen kleinen Unterschied:

*Er mag nicht schwimmen* macht keine Aussage darüber, ob er generell nicht gerne schwimmt oder nur momentan bzw. ausnahmsweise nicht schwimmen möchte.

*Er schwimmt nicht gern* bedeutet hingegen eindeutig, dass er grundsätzlich nicht gerne schwimmt.

**Hinweis zur Höflichkeitsform:**

Ausdrücke von der Form *jemand mag (nicht) …* sind umgangssprachlich und werden insbesondere von Kindern benutzt. In sachlichen Texten oder ernsten Gesprächen mit Respektpersonen sollte man stattdessen *jemand möchte (nicht)* benutzen. *Möchte* findet jedoch, anders als *mag*, nur Anwendung bei gegenwärtigen Wünschen. Bei allgemeinen Präferenzen benutzt man im formalen Kontext *bevorzugen*. Ausdrücke mit *wollen*, insbesondere *ich will*, sollten übrigens genauso umschrieben werden.

> Ich möchte ein Glas Wasser.
>   Ich bevorzuge die monatliche Auszahlung.
>   Ich möchte darüber nicht diskutieren.

Comment: *Er mag nicht schimmen* bedeutet eher, dass er gerade/einmalig nicht schimmen möchte. Würde er generell nicht gerne schimmen, würde man sagen *er mag schimmen nicht*.

Comment: Es gibt vermutlich eine leichte Tendenz, aber da dieser Ausdruck ohnehin schon hochgradig umgangssprachlich ist, würde ich mich nicht an eine allgemeingültige Deutung wagen.